# Filter out first element inside an array and leave actual array intact

Tags: json, jq

I have following JSON file:

```
{
    "Objects": [
        {
            "Key": "file.txt",
            "VersionId": "111111"
        },
        {
            "Key": "file.txt",
            "VersionId": "22222"
        },
        {
            "Key": "file.txt",
            "VersionId": "33333"
        },

    ]
}
```

and i need filter it somehow using JQ, so that output will be like this:

```
{
    "Objects": [
        {
            "Key": "file.txt",
            "VersionId": "22222"
        },
        {
            "Key": "file.txt",
            "VersionId": "33333"
        },

    ]
}
```

The structure must stay intact, and i only need to filter out the FIRST element in "Objects" array.
any other elements must stay intact.

I know there is a way to do something simmilar using ".[1:]" of JQ, but it filters out the actual .Object array also, and its something i cannot have..

example:

```
user@laptop:$ cat data.json | jq ' .Objects | .[1:]'                                                                                                                                             
[
  {
    "Key": "file.txt",
    "VersionId": "2222"
  },
  {
    "Key": "file.txt",
    "VersionId": "33333"
  }
]
```

Comment: Avoid useless `cat`: `jq 'filter' file` or `jq 'filter' < file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`|=` Update assignment](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:%7C=):

```
.Objects |= .[1:]
```

Or construct a new object:

```
{ Objects: .Objects[1:] }
```

It's also possible to [`del`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#del(path_expression)) an element from the array:

```
del(.Objects[0])
```

The last solution is probably closest to what you want to do, expressed in code, i.e. "delete the first array element".

Comment: +1
Amazing!!! you are a life saver!
Now it just works, i was hitting my head on the wall trying to figure out JQ..

cat data.json | jq '.Objects |= .[1:]'
{
  "Objects": [
    {
      "Key": "file.txt",
      "VersionId": "22222"
    },
    {
      "Key": "file.txt",
      "VersionId": "33333"
    }
  ]
}